# Found unknown command `\asf_license_start'

Tags: doxygen, atmel, atmelstudio

When trying to generate Doxygen documentation i get a lot of the warnings

```
Found unknown command `\asf_license_start'
```

Because i am using Atmel Software Framework (ASF) in my project. Hence a lot of my files has the licensing code as shown below. This code includes the command \asf_license_start and \asf_license_stop which are commands not known to Doxygen.

I have tried to look for external packages, but failed to find anything. I installed the Doxygen Integrator in Atmel Studios and changed the Doxygen Path to the location of my Doxygen installation.

Does anyone know what the \asf_license_start command should do in the documentation.

I hope that someone out there will be able to help me fix this issue as it is poluting the warning feedback and makes it harder to find the more critical issues.

```
 /**
 * \file
 *
 * \brief CDC Application Main functions
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011-2015 Atmel Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *
 * \asf_license_start
 *
 * \page License
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. The name of Atmel may not be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * 4. This software may only be redistributed and used in connection with an
 *    Atmel microcontroller product.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY ATMEL "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT ARE
 * EXPRESSLY AND SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL ATMEL BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,
 * STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
 * ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * \asf_license_stop
 *
 */
/*
 * Support and FAQ: visit <a href="http://www.atmel.com/design-support/">Atmel Support</a>
 */
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? It is strange that you get the message as it has 2 backslashes and thus the command is \\ but probably a result of some tests. Some further strange thing is the\page command withing the start stop pair. With the sistribution from Amtel there probably is also a doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) that defines the asf_license_start and asf_license_stop commands as a alias.

Comment: I am using Doxygen 1.8.8.

Comment: I apologize, the double \\ was an edit i made for it not to appear and i forgot to delete it in my post. But it is not a valid solution as "\asf_license_start" appears in all of the atmel files.
I have made an alias where "\asf_license_start" does nothing but i am worried that i might miss some information in my documentation that would be good to have. But in this way i avoid the warnings.
Do you have an idea of where i can find Atmel's doxygen configuration file, i have been looking for it without luck.

Comment: Best is to contact Atmel about this as they should know as they probably generated the original version.

Comment: Hi Albert
Thank you for your help.
I finally found a Doxyfile where they write the following
  ALIASES                += asf_license_start=" "
  ALIASES                += asf_license_stop=" "

I guess that means they do nothing, so i should be in the clear. I am new to doxygen, but i think it seems weird to add something that does nothing.

Anyways thanks for your fast response.

Comment: Good that you found the Doxyfile. It is not weird, it might be useful for other tools so the can "grep" the license information automatically.

Comment: Thats true, thanks for the explainations. Now i'm more confident i can just move on.